# iPhone up to date SBJSON tutorials

Tags: iphone, json

I have been trying to learn JSON parsing for both Android and iPhone as it is required for my job. I am quite comfortable with Android JSON parsing now as there are plenty of tutorials to use which are explained in detail.

However with iPhone development, I am having serious trouble trying to find any up to date SBJSON tutorial. All the ones I find online seem to be rather old which makes them difficult to follow, or they are not very well explained.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction of some good up to date tutorials, or  show me a basic example of JSON parsing on the iPhone using SBJSON. I need to be able to parse the data into a set of arrays.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a good tutorial after ages searching

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/

For anyone who wants a good in-depth tutorial, this link does the job. It explains the code quite well, so very useful.

Comment: And there's a newer version of this same tutorial on Touch Code Magazine now that demonstrates how to work with JSON the right way - by using proper data models: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the Examples folder in the source distribution? I wouldn't call them tutorials, but there's two fully functional example projects there.