# JSON data parsing in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I am parsing json data in iphone application. But it is not parsing it correct.

I am using the following code:

```
- (void)getSurveyList {     
       user_id=user_id;        
       NSLog(@"This is uerid %@",user_id);
       NSArray *tempArray =[[DataManager staticVersion] startParsing:@"http://myser-solutions.com/app/surveyList.php?user_id=user_id"];

       for (int i = 0; i<[tempArray count]; i++) {            
          id *item = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];    
          NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) item;        
          ObjectData *theObject =[[ObjectData alloc] init];
          [theObject setUser_id:[dict objectForKey:@"user_Id"]];
          [theObject setSurvey_Id:[dict objectForKey:@"survey_Id"]];
          [theObject setSurvey_Name:[dict objectForKey:@"survey_Name"]];
          [theObject setTotal_Question:[dict objectForKey:@"total_Question"]];  
          [theObject setAdministrator_Email:[dict objectForKey:@"administrator_Email"]];
          [theObject setStart_Date:[dict objectForKey:@"start_Date"]];
          [theObject setEnd_Date:[dict objectForKey:@"end_Date"]];      
          [theObject setStatus:[dict objectForKey:@"status"]];    
          [theObject setAdministrator_Email:[dict objectForKey:@"user_Password"]];    
          [surveyList addObject:theObject];    
          [theObject release];
          theObject=nil;            
          int count =[surveyList count];
          NSLog(@"Total is %d",count);               
      }
}
```

It does not enter in the loop while I debug the code. And I don't know why.

JSON RESPONSE

ali40[{"user_Id":"ali40","survey_Id":"1","survey_Name":"Veritas Survey","total_Questions":"20","administrator_Email":"engr.jamshedali@hotmail.com","start_Date":"20-9-2012","end_Date":"1-10-2012","status":"Active","user_Password":"jackson12"},{"user_Id":"ali40","survey_Id":"2","survey_Name":"Celeritas Survey","total_Questions":"20","administrator_Email":"jani_06sw@yahoo.com","start_Date":"10-11-2012","end_Date":"12-12-2012","status":"Active","user_Password":"jackson12"}]

Comment: `id *item` should really be `id item`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425923/how-to-assign-values-from-nsmutabledictionary-to-nsarray/12426282#12426282  see this link

Comment: @H2CO3 nothing changed i have alos tried like this

Comment: @ShahzadBaloch I know, that's unrelated to the problem, but it still should be `id` and not `id *`.

Comment: @H3CO3 i thisk probel is while given user_id in url

Comment: can you please show json response..

Comment: @Rajneesh071 i have show json response

Comment: are you getting something in tempArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parsing may be incorrect.The temp array is returned nil.Check on the parsing Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) and on SBJSON [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083160/iphone-up-to-date-sbjson-tutorials)
Three things to check on

- Input -Fetched properly
- Is it valid JSON response
- Properly parsed

Comment: i have addes json response check that

Comment: please make your statements clear in proper english.May get banned if not done so

Answer (score 0):

If it is not entering in the loop then `tempArray` must be empty. Please check once again.

Comment: it mean url is not sending user_id

Comment: i can accept but why temp array is empty while there is data coming from json

Comment: can you please tell me why it is showing empty is there any probel in code

Comment: why You have kept        user_id=user_id;        ?

Comment: The parsing may be incorrect.The temp array is nil because of that.

Comment: check more on json parsing http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5